# What are the locally optimal points in an LP formulation of the max flow problem?

Tags: linear-programming, network-flow, minimum-cuts

I'm taking a grad level algorithms course and we just ended the course talking about linear programming, and we had previously talked about the max flow/min cut problem. Our professor said that the max flow/min cut problem can be formulated as an LP problem.

I asked the professor what the non feasible but locally optimal points in the LP formulation of the max flow/min cut problem correspond to in the max flow/min cut problem (more so the max flow part, I think he said the dual problem was min cut and we talked a little bit about what feasible points in the min cut problem were), but he couldn't think of the answer off the top of his head.

I was wondering if anyone here knew.